# How to prevent the paired bluetooth device from being connected by other apk?

Tags: android, bluetooth

It is possible to connect to a remote device from the paired list. However, for security reason, can i secure the paired bluetooth device to be connected by authorized apk only?

Comment: you can't limit other apps from connecting to certain device *on Android side*. However, you may do that on your custom protocol side\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution that i can give is that if you can program the Bluetooth device with a unique UUID and in you application set it as your application will connect to only that UUID and the Bluetooth will give access to only those applications with that particular UUID then your problem can be solve or then there is no other solution to do this. for example you can check out the HM10 BLE Bluetooth that provides this functionality

Hope this helps you 
Happy coding......